# Promise.all doesn't catch errors

Tags: javascript, error-handling, promise

I'm struggling to handle errors with Promise.all:

```
return Promise.all([
  this.pagination(),
  this.prepareParams(this.params, this.requestData),
  this.fetchRecipes(this.apiData, this.params)
])
  .catch(e => console.log());
```

Firstly I've just tried to throw an exception in `this.pagination()`, it was even handled, but strangely enough the next Promises were despite executed.

```
pagination(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {

    if(...) {
      ...
      resolve();

    } else {
      ...
      throw "no more results";
    }
}
```

Then I tried to use `Promise.reject("no more results")` instead, but the problem is that it ignores now somehow my `catch`

> Uncaught (in promise): no more results

## UPDATE

Just to clarify for others: My original intention was to prevent the execution of the next 2 Promises, if the first one was rejected. Mistakenly I assumed that `Promise.all` fulfills this requirement. Thanks to the answer of traktor53 I realised that chaining promises is a better solution.

Comment: A throw in a promise constructor with the promise being passed to promise.all works fine for me. https://jsfiddle.net/md63x4dr/1/

Comment: Are you sure that throw isn't in an async callback or some other weird place?

Comment: @KevinB yeah, `pagination` ist quite simple, it should just operate with `offset`, `amount` and `totalNumber` so I didn't use anything apart from if's and simple math.

Comment: @RomanDorokhov Please post your full, actual code of the function

Comment: What do you mean by "*the next Promises were despite executed.*"? You cannot expect `prepareParams` and `fetchRecipes` not to be called just because `pagination` rejects (possibly in the future). If that is what you want, put an `if` around the whole `Promise.all` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.all` waits for all the promises in its argument array to be fulfilled before returning an array of results, but will reject the promise it returned as soon as *any* of the promises in the array become rejected ("fast rejection").

`Promise.all` calls `then` on each of the promises passed to obtain its fulfilled value or rejected reason. *It does not attempt to abort other promises if one of them is rejected* - there is no mechanism in Promise standards to cancel a promised operation.

If you want to continue execution of promise operations only after a preceding promise is successful, use chaining rather than `promise.all`, taking care that the `this` value is correct in promise call backs (e.g. by using arrow functions):

```
function objectMethod () {
    return this.pagination()
    .then( data=>this.prepareParams(this.params, this.requestData))
    .then( data=>this.fetchRecipes(this.apiData, this.params));
}

// catch errors encountered during call:
someObject.someMethod().catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it solved perfectly my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The [callback parameter to the `Promise` constructor (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Parameters) takes two arguments, idomatically called `resolve` and `reject`, the latter of which you are missing. Instead of throwing the error, you must pass it to `reject`. Therefore:

```
pagination(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    if(...) {
      ...
      resolve();

    } else {
      ...
      reject("no more results");
    }
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be required.

Comment: In this case it just ignores `reject` and executes all 3 Promises

Comment: @KevinB it's not required if and only if the executor operation is synchronous - in which case the throw will be caught by `try/catch` statements around the call to the executor. In the case of checking asynchronous results it is required.

Comment: @traktor53 Yes, and in this sample there's no async operations occurring. We can only go by what the OP gives us.

Answer (score 0):

Better to add 
try - catch block when you call a function

else

```
pagination(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       if(...) {
          ...
          resolve();

       } else {
          ...
          reject("no more results");
       }
}
```

In your function call.

```
pagination().then(err, value) {}
```